# Подключение VPN в Selenium 4

Tags: python, selenium, vpn

Нужно зайти на сайт, недоступный с РФ. На [оф. сайте](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/#proxy) нашёл решение и мой код выглядит пока что так:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "<HOST:PORT>"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
"httpProxy": PROXY,
"ftpProxy": PROXY,
"sslProxy": PROXY,
"proxyType": "MANUAL",
}

with webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
    driver.get("https://2ip.ru/")
```

Нужно подключить VPN или прокси со сменой региона для 4(!) версии селениума. В интернете написаны устаревшие решения

**Буду благодарен за любую помощь**